# Invalid operation: statement is closed. ERRORCODE=-4470, SQLSTATE=null

Tags: hibernate, transactions

Below is my DAO Impl method which calls database which works fine in single thread but when I deploy in multi node environment getting the error and also lock not getting released

```
@Transactional
public long getSequenceUniqueId()throws Exception {
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

long minVal = 0L;
long maxVal = 0L;
long existingId=0L;
try
{
    MySequence myEntityObj = (MySequence) session.load(MySequence.class, ID, LockMode.UPGRADE);
    existingId=myEntityObj.getSequence();
    maxVal=myEntityObj.getMaxVal();
    minVal=myEntityObj.getMinVal();
    existingId = existingId+1;
    myEntityObj.setSequence(existingId);
    session.update(myEntityObj);
    session.flush();
}catch(Exception lAE)
{
    lAE.printStackTrace();
}
return existingId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try flushing and closing in a finally clause:

```
@Transactional
public long getSequenceUniqueId()throws Exception {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    long existingId=0L;
    try {
        MySequence myEntityObj = (MySequence) session.load(MySequence.class, ID, LockMode.UPGRADE);
        existingId = myEntityObj.getSequence() + 1;
        myEntityObj.setSequence(existingId);
        session.update(myEntityObj);
    } catch(Exception lAE) {
        lAE.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.flush();
        session.close();
    }
    return existingId;
}
```

Comment: Any luck with the suggestion?

Comment: I will try and let you know, however I just have a question here that if I don't close the session manually, I am under the impression that hibernate closes it after auto-commit. Is my understanding correct? For your information we are using hibernate data source and WAS connection pooling to get the connection and handle the connections.

Comment: Dear JC Carrillo - Any update? is my understanding correct?

Comment: hibernate closes the connection once the flow is done with it, although it doesn't hurt to do it.

Comment: I have tried this but no luck, lock not getting released as a result I can see lock waits on the DB2 database and application not being processed.